# yum/ zypper for non-root installation in independent rpm database

Tags: linux, rpm, yum, zypper

My company is developing a Linux based software product which is shipped to different customers.
The product it self consits out of small software components which interact with each other.

What we usually ship as an update/ new release to the customer are the the current versions of the different software components e.g. compA-2.0.1, compB-3.2.3 and compC-4.1.2

Currently we employ a rather simple shell script for the installation/ upgarding process. However, we'd like to move forwarard to state of the art packaging, mainly to have an easy way of swapping different versions of components, keeping track of files and the packages they belong to and also to provide the customers with an easier interface for the update/ installation.

The software components are installed in different directories, depending on the customers demands. So it could be in `/opt`, `/usr/local` or something completely different.

Since the vast majority of our customers runs on rpm-based Linux distributions we decided for rpm-packages instead of dpkg.

In rpm terms our problem is a non-root installation. This is realativly straight forward using the following features:

- own rpm database using the `--dbpath` option
- installing in different locations using the `Prefix` mechanism
- optional: disabling auto library dependancies using `AutoReqProv: no` in the rpm spec file

Using those features/ options allows us to create rpm packages which can be installed using the `rpm` command line tool as non-root user.

However, what we really would like to see is to install those packages via a http repository with either `yum` or `zypper`. The latter one is the tool of choice in SUSE based distributions.

**The problem we see is, that non of the tools is providing the required alternative rpm database option (`--dbath` in rpm) and prefix support required for a non-root installation.**

**Does anybody have a suggestion/ idea how to deal with this issue? Is there maybe a third package-tool with we're not aware of?**

Or should we maybe go a totally different route? I had a play with GNU `stow` and wrote some very simplistic yum-like logic around it - but then I would basically start my own package installation tool which I tried to circumvent.

Comment: Beginning to sound like [0Install](http://0install.net/) with a client-defined directory?